# Why do you need to have the exact method as the base class when you extend a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

It has something to do with inheritance, but I still have no idea how to connect those two things together. For example, why can't public void paint(Graphics pane) be public void draw(Graphics pane) or public void paint(Graphics pane, int x, int y)?

Answer (score 0):

Classes that extend Frame don't *have* to override any method. They *can* override any method they want to expand the default behavior of Frame (such as painting a custom background), including all of the paint() method you mentioned above.

The other methods you mentioned aren't defined in the Frame class, so Java doesn't know to call them.

But like I said, there is no rule saying that you *have* to override any of the above methods. But if you aren't overriding any methods, why are you extending Frame in the first place?

On the other hand, you should probably be using JFrame and not Frame.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you would change the method signature, then there would be no inheritance anymore.

Inheritance is essential if you need other objects functionality, ie. `class X extends JPanel`.